# Fatal Error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I tried to route with using name .

I already tried to solve with using Composer update , Clear Cache , Generate App key.

But it's showing fatal error .

Error View Message :

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found
in ClassesController.php line 13
```

My Route Code Below :

```
<?php
  Route::prefix('Classes')->group(function(){
  Route::get('/add','ClassesController@index')->name('AddNewClass');
});
```

My Controller Code Below :

```
<?php
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;



  class ClassesController extends Controller{
    public function index()
     {
       return "Method Access";
     }
```

Comment: Well... did you delete your Controller.php file in app/Http/Controllers?

Comment: @Devon no sir i didn't

Comment: Try changing `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` to simply `use Controller;` since both files use the same namespace.

Comment: @AdamMcquiff sir .. its showing this error :  The use statement with non-compound name 'Controller' has no effect

Comment: Try removing the statement altogether.

Comment: @AdamMcquiff sir .. actually now its showing : Class 'Controller' not found

Comment: Does the file containing the class 'Controller' exist in the same directory with the same namespace, as implied in your code?

Comment: If it doesn't, then you can either create the class or instead you can just remove `extends Controller`.

Comment: @AdamMcquiff no sir.

Comment: I would advise you just remove the `extends Controller` then.

Comment: Great ... its working @AdamMcquiff ..... thank you so much sir.

Comment: You're very welcome - I've provided my solution as an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this event, I would first ensure that the file containing the class `Controller` exists in the same directory with the same namespace as the `ClassesController`, as implied in your code.

If the `Controller` does not exist, you can either create the class or simply remove the `extends Controller` and the line `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

its worked for me.
usercontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     */

    /* http://localhost:8080/laravelapps/blog/public/staff */
    public function showProfile()
    {
       return 'new';
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/staff', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

http://localhost:8080/laravelapps/blog/public/staff

Answer (score 0):

- Check whether Controller.php file exists or not in your Controllers folder if not exists download or put from laravel project.
- After that run following command php artisan app:name newproject
- Make sure in the above line i have updated text 'newproject' that should be first line of your Controller.php file. For example: namespace newproject\Http\Controllers;